# updating value of the Target cell in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to update the value of the Target cell using VBA macro when it exists in particular Range.  I want to update its value as by concatenating a string to its value. For example if some writes 250 in the Target cell, I want to write back "XYZ-250" into the target cell.  Below is the code:

```
Dim oldCellAddress As String
Dim oldCellValue As String
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
oldCellValue = 0
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E10:E500")) Is Nothing Then
oldCellValue = Target.Value
Sheet1.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = "AST-" & oldCellValue
End If
End Sub
```

Interestingly when I change the value of any cell within the range (E10 to E500) the messagebox is displayed infinite times and halts the excel and I have to restart it again.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it not intersect(target.address, range("E10:E500))? Sorry, just my first feeling. Strange a message box would appear...

Comment: @Lowpar My guess is that the OP was using a MsgBox to track whether the function was being called, but didn't post that line in the question.  (But I could be wrong.)

Comment: @YowE3K yeah, I just realized the infinite loop was caused by the cell itself changing, causing a recursive function which would consistently repeat the same action. Great solution to disable events!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable events prior to making any change that will fire the `Change` event:

```
Dim oldCellAddress As String
Dim oldCellValue As String
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    oldCellValue = 0
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E10:E500")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        oldCellValue = Target.Value
        Target.Value = "AST-" & oldCellValue
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

If events aren't disabled, your change to the cell will fire the `Worksheet_Change` event, which will change the cell, which will fire the `Worksheet_Change` event, which will change the cell, which will fire the `Worksheet_Change` event, which will change the cell, which will fire the `Worksheet_Change` event, which will change the cell, which will fire the ...

---

Assuming you don't need your `oldCellValue` and `oldCellAddress` module-scope variables, but do want to handle changes to multiple cells, use this instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E10:E500")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim c As Range
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each c In Intersect(Target, Range("E10:E500")).Cells
            c.Value = "AST-" & c.Value
        Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to note: it's possible that `Target` could represent >1 cell, or even a whole row/column.  In those cases, just because the intersect between `Target` and a given range is not `Nothing` does not mean that *all* of the `Target` range lies within your range of interest.  So checking for an intersect and then going ahead to operate on Target could give unexpected results.

Comment: @TimWilliams I had thought of that, but I wasn't sure why the OP was using `oldCellValue` and `oldCellAddress`. (Possibly to have the old value and new values available somewhere else in [unposted] code?).  Keeping track of "old" values while handling multiple concurrent changes (or even multiple sequential changes) seemed like too much effort for a "disable the Events" answer, but I have added an alternative which handles multiple changes **without** implying the maintenance of the "old" variables.

Comment: Yes good point -  the globals - which are typed as String - would cause an error if multiple cells are updated...

Comment: Thank you all, Its working fine now just by disabling and enabling the events properly.