# Updating value of a non-Target cell in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I found the [attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001033/updating-value-of-the-target-cell-in-excel-vba) when looking for how to due an event change to correct user data based on the values in two columns.  I'm not a programmer, so I may have butchered the code as I combined two different solutions together.

Right now, it's working exactly as I want it to.  Changing the offset cell value forces Excel to replace the target value with what I've specified.  What I'm looking to achieve (and am not sure is possible), is to reverse the code.  Basically, I want to change the offset cell, if the values are entered in the opposite order.  The code will change the cell value to "Beta" if a user enters "Bravo" in column A, and then "Gamma" in column C.

What I'm trying to achieve is that if the user enters "Bravo" in column A second, that Excel still sees the combination of these cells and still replaces the value with "Beta".  I know this is additional code, but I couldn't find anything to support replacing cell when the target cell isn't the value being updated.

Thanks in advance!

```
Dim oldCellAddress As String
Dim oldCellValue As String
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    oldCellValue = "Bravo"
        If Target = "Bravo" And Target.Offset(0, -2) = "Gamma" Then
        Target.Value = "Beta"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As per the existing code, the sheet change event will be triggered if you change the content of any cell on the sheet. Is this what you want? OR you want it to be triggered only with specific column where you want to place Beta after checking the column A and C in the corresponding row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may meet your needs:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim colnum As Long, v As Variant

    colnum = Target.Column
    v = Target.Value

    If colnum = 1 Then
        If v = "Bravo" And Target.Offset(0, 2) = "Gamma" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Value = "Beta"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If colnum = 3 And v = "Gamma" And Target.Offset(0, -2) = "Bravo" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Offset(0, -2).Value = "Beta"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

For example if the user puts *Bravo* in cell **A1** and **C1** already contained *Gamma*, the code puts *Beta* in **A1** *(the code corrects the **A1** entry)*.
If the user puts *Gamma* in cell **C1** and cell **A1** already contained *Bravo*, the code corrects **A1**.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible scenarios like below...

**Scenario 1:**

If `ANY CELL` on the sheet is changed, the following code will check the content of `column A` and `C` in the `corresponding row` and change the content of the `Target Cell`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim r As Long
r = Target.Row
On Error GoTo Skip:
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Cells(r, "A") = "Bravo" And Cells(r, "C") = "Gamma" Then
    Target.Value = "Beta"
End If
Skip:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Scenario 1:**

If `a cell in column D` is changed, the change event will be triggered and check the content in `column A` and `C` in the `corresponding row` and change the `Target Cell in Column D`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim r As Long
On Error GoTo Skip:
'The below line ensures that the sheet change event will be triggered when a cell in colunm D is changed
'Change it as per your requirement.
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    r = Target.Row
    If Cells(r, "A") = "Bravo" And Cells(r, "C") = "Gamma" Then
        Target.Value = "Beta"
    End If
End If
Skip:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```